# Asynchronous behaviour. Recursive setTimeout doesn't complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I don't get why my program doesn't finish the recursive function, before executing the next line of code.

```
console.clear();
var a = 1;

function logA() {
  if (a<11) {
    console.log(a);
    a++;
    setTimeout(logA, 100);
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
}

logA();
console.log("after set timeout");
```

sample:
https://jsbin.com/moyanudeki/edit?js,console

What's going on in the stack?

Comment: change setTimeout(logA, 100); to setTimeout(logA(), 100); you forgot the ()

Comment: I just want to understand how the call stack behaves. I would think I should see 1...10 logged before "after set timeout"

Comment: @Mgasmi No, that causes it to not work at all

Comment: @Mgasmi unless I'm mistaken, that would execute the logA function, rather than pass it to the setTimeout for execution after the delay. So I would get the output I need, but not the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your `logA()` function is called for the first time then `if` block is executed as expected. `setTimeout(logA, 100);` is called for the first time.

In Javascript `setTimeout()` runs asynchronously and therefore it will wait in stack for 100ms and the next statement which is `console.log("after set timeout");` gets executed. After this logA function from first timeout gets executed which triggers one more timeout and so on.

So your output is as expected:

```
1
"after set timeout"
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no recursion here. `setTimeout`, as the name suggests, schedules a function for asynchronous execution, after the set amount of time (100ms, in this case) has expired. That doesn't stop the current batch of code from running.

I.e. `logA()` will return, the console prints `"after set timeout"`, and then the VM waits for the 100ms to expire. When that happens, it executes `logA()`, which schedules itself again, and so on.

Just to be clear, *this* would be recursion:

```
console.clear();
var a = 1;

function logA() {
  if (a<11) {
    console.log(a);
    a++;
    logA();
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
}

logA();
console.log("after recursion");
```

Comment: Why do you say that there is no recursion? Even though it's wrapped in another function (setTimeout), logA is still called from within itself.

Comment: No, it's not. `logA()` calls `setTimeout()`, and then returns. When the timer expires, the VM calls `logA()`, but at that point the previous invocation of `logA()` is no longer on the call stack. That's why this doesn't qualify as recursion.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks. What about if instead of a setTimeout, I wrap it in IIFE  like this: (function(){logA()})();  Would it be a recursion then?

Comment: We're veering into semi-philosophical territory here, but I'd say it technically is recursion, because it's the same call stack. Just checked on Wikipedia, and this would count as "indirect recursion".

Answer (score 1):

Also maybe interesting for you in understanding how the stack behaves in javascript is understanding the event loop. In javascript first the stack is emptied and then are the asynchronous callbacks executed which are stacked up in the event queue.

In your example when we have the following code:

```js
function test () {
  console.log('first log');
}

setTimeout(test, 0);

console.log('last log');
```

Now the function object test is passed in the event queue. After the stack is cleared this function gets executed.

But if you execute the function directy like this:

```js
    function test () {
      console.log('first log');
    }

    setTimeout(test(), 0);

    console.log('last log');
```

Now the function code will be directly executed and the function will not end up in the event queue.

Hopefully this is helpful